# Why transition is applying to active state despite only being specified on normal state

Tags: html, css

The transition that I applied to the normal state is being applied to the arrow on the active state. Notice that when the button is clicked, it takes the arrow `.3s` to turn from white to the same color as the rest of the active state. How can I remove this transition from the arrow's active state while keeping the transition of the button background on hover?

I tried removing `transition: all .3s` from `.btn` but this removes the hover state background color delay as well. I want to keep this.

```css
body {
  background: #00b894;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 60px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  line-height: 58px;
  background: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  transition: all .3s;
  /* This is causing a transition on the arrow's active state */
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #009E7E;
}

.btn:active {
  border-color: #008066;
  color: #008066;
}

.btn:before {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.btn--continue:before {
  left: 130%;
}

.btn--continue:hover:before {
  left: 80%;
}

.icon-arrow-right:before {
  content: "→";
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn--continue icon-arrow-right">Continue</button>
```

I want the white arrow to immediately turn into the same color as the rest of the active state. Basically, remove the .3s transition. However, I want to keep the hover button background delay.

Comment: You shouldn't be specifying `all` on the transition value, change it to only be the properties you wish to animate.

Answer (score 1):

Set your transition to: `transition: background .3s;`